# HTTP request reader

Tags: java, http

I'm working on a proxy service that will run on top of a Java application in order to manipulate some headers. I've just completed the first step and that is intercepting the request message and storing them.

This code features only the storage part, and not the edit and send part.

Some information about HTTP requests:

1. A request consists of header lines, seperated by a newline.
2. The header is terminated by an extra newline.
3. After that possibly there is additional content, the message payload.

Some assumptions I make in this code:

- It assumes the data is input over a `Socket`.
- It works for both `\n` and `\r\n` newlines.
- It assumes the `US-ASCII` character set for header.
- It can only deal with either no `Content-Length` or with normal content length, it does not know about chunked data (yet).

Extra caution may be paid to if the trade-off of bloated code due to increased low level performance versus concise code is worth it.

```
public final class Converter {
    private Converter() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    private static final int LINE_FEED_BYTE = 10; //'\n'
    private static final int CARRIAGE_RETURN_BYTE = 13; //'\r'

    public static void socketToMessages(final Socket socket, final BlockingQueue<Message> messages) {
        listeningLoop:
        while (true) {
            List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
            int newlineCount = 0;
            StringBuilder headerStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                byte[] byteArray = new byte[1];
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                boolean readingHeader = true;
                while (readingHeader) {
                    int b = inputStream.read();
                    if (b == -1) {
                        break listeningLoop;
                    }
                    else if (b == LINE_FEED_BYTE) {
                        newlineCount++;
                        String header = headerStringBuilder.toString();
                        headers.add(header);
                        headerStringBuilder.setLength(0);
                        if (newlineCount == 2) {
                            readingHeader = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (b == CARRIAGE_RETURN_BYTE) {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                    else {
                        newlineCount = 0;
                        byteArray[0] = (byte)b;
                        headerStringBuilder.append(new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
                    }
                }

                byte[] contentBytes = new byte[0];
                Optional<String> contentLengthOptional = Message.getHeaderValue(headers, "Content-Length");
                if (contentLengthOptional.isPresent()) {
                    try {
                        int contentLength = Integer.parseInt(contentLengthOptional.get());
                        contentBytes = new byte[contentLength];
                        int totalReadBytes = 0;
                        while (totalReadBytes < contentLength) {
                            int readBytes = inputStream.read(contentBytes, totalReadBytes, contentLength - totalReadBytes);
                            if (readBytes == -1) {
                                break listeningLoop;
                            }
                            totalReadBytes += readBytes;
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                }
                messages.add(new Message(headers, contentBytes));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Message {
    private final List<String> headers;
    private final byte[] content;

    public Message(final List<String> headers, final byte[] content) {
        this.headers = Objects.requireNonNull(headers, "headers");
        this.content = Objects.requireNonNull(content, "content");
    }

    public List<String> getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    public byte[] getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public static Optional<String> getHeaderValue(final List<String> headers, final String key) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(headers, "headers");
        Objects.requireNonNull(key, "key");
        for (String header : headers) {
            String[] words = header.split(" ");
            if (words[0].contains(":")) {
                String foundKey = words[0].replace(":", "");
                if (foundKey.equals(key)) {
                    return Optional.of(String.join(" ", Arrays.asList(words).subList(1, words.length)));
                }
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

An example request is:

```
GET http://top.secret.mil/secretservices/services/TopSecretServices?wsdl HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0
Host: top.secret.mil
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

Example calling code is:

```
BlockingQueue<Message> messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
new Thread(() -> Converter.socketToMessages(socket, messages)).start();
while (true) {
    try {
        Message message = messages.take();
        message.getHeaders().forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println(message.getContent().length);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.interrupted();
    }
}
```

I'd like a review on all aspects of this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## socketToMessages()

There are a number of things in here to report:

1. there is no need for the labelled loop `listeningLoop`. Th places you use the label, you have `break listeningLoop;`, and those can simply be replaced with `return`.
2. You read a single byte at a time from the InputStream when you are processing the headers. This is really slow (especially since the input source is from the network, where the network stack is often not very fast for small requests). You need to create a buffer, and read a chunk of data at a time. When the data is in the buffer, you need to be smart about how you loop through it, looking for the newlines and header-end sections.
3. This code is probably quite accurate, but could be simplified:

   > ```
   > byteArray[0] = (byte)b;
   > headerStringBuilder.append(new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
   > ```

   as

   ```
   headerStringBuilder.append((char)b);
   ```

   That converts the int val to a char, and it's done. You are already assuming US_ASCII so there is no loss in here.

## getHeaderValue()

Why is this a static? It should be an instance method, and there should be no need for the List input.

```
public Optional<String> getHeaderValue(final String key) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(key, "key");
    for (String header : headers) {
        .....
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Also, there are a few bugs in here.....

1. The [HTTP specification says](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2):

   > Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. ***Field names are case-insensitive.*** The field value MAY be preceded by any amount of LWS, though a single SP is preferred. Header fields can be extended over multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at least one SP or HT.

   Your code is using a case-sensitive match, and also, it is not very efficient.
2. HTTP allows some headers to be present multiple times:

   > Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma.

   What this means is that you may have to scan for multiple instances of the same field if you don't know whether the field is specified as `#(values)`.
3. You expect a space between the colon in the header, and the field value. This space is not required. The header `Content-length:1029` is fine.... though a single-space is 'preferred'.

I would recommend a helper function that does:

```
private static final String extractValue(final String key, final String field) {
    if (key.length() >= field.length()) {
        return null;
    }
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < key.length()) {
        if (Character.toLowerCase(key.charAt(pos)) != Character.toLowerCase(field.charAt(pos))) {
            return null;
        }
        pos++;
    }
    if (field.charAt(pos++) != ':') {
        return null;
    }

    return field.substring(pos);
}
```

Then, in your code, you can loop through your headers like:

```
public Optional<String> getHeaderValue(final String key) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(key, "key");
    for (String header : headers) {
        String val = extractValue(key, header);
        if (val != null) {
            return Optional.of(val);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

The code is much simpler to read, and it is only doing string manipulation on a single field. It is not breaking and reconstructing the data in spaces, and it is just plain simpler.

Comment: Minor comment: `getHeaderValue` is currently static, because I need to use it on other places as well, I figured it could be an instance method of `Message`, but I cannot call it here yet before the message object has been constructed.

Comment: Also when thinking about `Message` should the constructor not make a defensive copy of the input, and should the get... methods not return a defensive copy?

Comment: If you have reasons for making your method static (which may be valid, but are not shown in your question's code), then sure, have a satic method. Call the static method something else, and keep the isntance method, the instance method can just call the static version with it's headers as an argument. About the defensive copies, I am on the fence. If your code is not a 'library', then the only person you have to defend against is yourself. For performance reasons, I often skip the defensive copies for code used in a single application